# How should I finger A# and F# Major on piano?

Tags: piano, chords, fingering

How should I finger A# and F# Major with the left hand, 5-2-1 or 5-3-1?

Comment: In terms of fingering, context is everything.  Are you asking how to finger the chords for exercises or for a piece? If it's the latter, we'd need to know what notes are around the chord to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to lay all major/minor chords in first inversion as 5-3-1 (or 1-3-5 in the right hand).  In most cases, F# Major included, doing anything else will generally cramp your fingers and make it harder to play.

The A# one could alternatively be played 4-2-1.  This might help if you're having trouble stretching with your pinky to the black key.

Comment: Do you mean root position or first inversion? (Most often I'd play first inversion RH 1-2-5, not 1-3-5. Root position 1-3-5 is fine.)